# Displays the current value taken from ENUM in form

Tags: php, enums

I have a field in the mysql database of type "ENUM",
the field is called "career_status" and these values are stored,
Active, 
Retired, 
Dead

I created a form for update, the one I would like and display the current value in the form.
Example:
if now it is stored Active displaying Active in the form, if nothing is empty etc ..
How to get these values from the field?
this is the code

```html
<?php

require_once("connetti.php");

$actor_id = $_GET["id"];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM actor  WHERE actor_id=" .  (int)$actor_id) or die ("Error in query: " . mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($query);

$nome=$row['nome'];
$performer_aka=$row['performer_aka'];
$website=$row['website'];
$career_status=$row['career_status'];
$birthday=$row['birthday'];
$died=$row['died'];
$status=$row['status'];



?>

<div id="BioData" style="overflow: hidden;">

<center><h1><?php echo $nome;?> <span class="infoblock-pagetype">modifica dati</span></h1></center>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?id=' . $actor_id; ?>" method="post">

<tr>
<td class="paramname">
<b>Career Status: </b> (<b><font color="red">selezionare il valore</font></b>)
</td>
<td class="paramvalue"> 
<select name="career_status" id="career_status"><?php echo $career_status;?>
<option value="1">Active</option>
<option value="2">Retired</option>
<option value="3">Dead</option>
<option value="0">      </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['modifica']))
{
 //include "connetti.php";
 //$query = mysql_select_db("xxx", $db);
 if ($query)
  {

 $nome=$_POST['nome'];
 $performer_aka=$_POST['performer_aka'];
 $website=$_POST['website'];
 $career_status=$_POST['career_status'];
 $birthday=$_POST['birthday'];
 $died=$_POST['died'];
 $status=$_POST['status'];
 
    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE actor SET 
 nome='".$_POST['nome']."', 
 performer_aka='".$_POST['performer_aka']."',
 website='".$_POST['website']."',
 career_status='".$_POST['career_status']."',
 birthday='".$_POST['birthday']."',
 died='".$_POST['died']."',
 status='".$_POST['status']."'
 WHERE actor_id=". $actor_id);



   if($query) echo "<h2>Congratulazioni! Dati inseriti.</h2>";
    else echo "<h2>Attenzione! Dati non inseriti!</h2>";
   
 } else echo "<h2>Errore! Database non selezionato.</h2>";
 
 
}

?>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid. You cannot nest a table row within a form form within like that nor can you break the flow of the HTML table across other elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that you wish to indicate which `career_status` option is currently selected for the record then perhaps the following might help

```
<select name='career_status'>           
    <?php
        /* possible options for career status */
        $status=array(
            0=>'',
            1=>'Active',
            2=>'Retired',
            3=>'Dead'
        );

        for( $i=0; $i < count( $status ); $i++ ){
            /* is this item selected? */
            $selected = $i==$career_status ? ' selected' : '';
            printf('
                <option value="%d"%s>%s', 
                $i, 
                $selected, 
                $status[ $i ]
            );
        }

    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: hi RamRaider,
Thanks for the reply
the form code cut it (not complete)
where should I enter your code?, at what exact point?
sorry, I don't know php well yet, I just started,
ps: I'm not a programmer, my job is something else, just passion.

Comment: replace all of your `<select name="career_status".... ` to `....</select>` with the above

Comment: thanks, but I would like to display (already selected) the current value in the form, look screenshot [link] (https://yadi.sk/i/-TN7CW5ghBDvAQ)

Comment: the field correct is "$career_status=$row['career_status'];, I changed the code but the value is not selectet, <select name='career_status'>
`code`

        for( $i=0; $i < count( $career_status ); $i++ ){
            /* is this item selected? */
            $selected = $i==$career_status ? ' selected' : '';
            printf('
                <option value="%d"%s>%s', 
                $i, 
                $selected, 
                $career_status[ $i ]
            );
        }

    ?>
</select>`code`

Comment: what is the value of `$row['career_status']`? 1,2,3??

Comment: `1=>'Active', 2=>'Retired', 3=>'Dead' `

Comment: this work with code, think `<option selected value="<?php echo $career_status; ?>"><?php  echo $career_status; ?>`

Comment: thanks RamRaider
seems to work with the extra code, and right? you confirm?